# How to remove a task from DAG

Tags: airflow

I have a couple of defined tasks that should be reused (defined once) and depending on some variable `mode` are wired in different ways and some tasks might be fully excluded in the desired dag, but at the moment can't find an easy way how to programmatically exclude all those tasks from the `dag` tasks collection?

(e.g. in mode `C` tasks `t3` and `t5` should not be part of the dag.)

I'm aware of `BranchPythonOperator` and `triggering_rule`s but the DAG becomes super complex because `depends_on_past` semantics is needed at every task instance.

```py
mode = 'A' or 'B' or 'C'

with DAG(dag_id=mode,
         start_date=...,
         schedule_interval=...,
         default_args=...) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='t1')
    t2 = DummyOperator(task_id='t2')
    t3 = DummyOperator(task_id='t3')
    t4 = DummyOperator(task_id='t4')
    t5 = DummyOperator(task_id='t5')

    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    if mode='A':
      start >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4 >> t5 >> end
    elif mode='B':
      start >> [t1, t2] >> t3 >> t4 >> t5 >> end
    elif mode='C':
      start >> t1 >> t4 >> t2 >> end

    for i, t in enumerate(dag.tasks):
        if t.task_id not in end.upstream_task_ids:
            # dag.tasks[i].dag = None # error, has no dag setter 
            dag.tasks.remove(t) # doesn't help
```

Would be nice to have `dag.remove_task(...)` the same way [`dag.add_task(...)`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/models/dag.html#DAG.add_task) works.

Comment: Have you consider `BranchPythonOperator`?

Comment: I mentioned it in my question.

Comment: sorry I was blind. :'(

Answer (score 0):

I found one "ugly" solution using **task factory methods** that have `dag` as a parameter.

```sql
mode = 'A' or 'B' or 'C'

def start(dag: DAG): return DummyOperator(dag=dag,task_id='start')
def t1(dag: DAG): return DummyOperator(dag=dag,task_id='t1')
def t2(dag: DAG): return DummyOperator(dag=dag,task_id='t2')
def t3(dag: DAG): return DummyOperator(dag=dag,task_id='t3')
def t4(dag: DAG): return DummyOperator(dag=dag,task_id='t4')
def t5(dag: DAG): return DummyOperator(dag=dag,task_id='t5')
def end(dag:DAG): return DummyOperator(dag=dag,task_id='end')


with DAG(dag_id=mode,
         start_date=...,
         schedule_interval=...,
         default_args=...) as dag:

    if mode='A':
      start(dag) >> t1(dag) >> t2(dag) >> t3(dag) >> t4(dag) >> t5(dag) >> end(dag)
    elif mode='B':
      start(dag) >> [t1(dag), t2(dag)] >> t3(dag) >> t4(dag) >> t5(dag) >> end(dag)
    elif mode='C':
      start(dag) >> t1(dag) >> t4(dag) >> t2(dag) >> end(dag)
```